# urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Tags: python, entity-framework, google-translate

my code goes like this

```
def translate(self, to_translate, to_langage="auto", langage="auto"):

 '''Return the translation using google translate
    you must shortcut the langage you define (French = fr, English = en, Spanish = es,    etc...)
    if you don't define anything it will detect it or use english by default
    Example:
    print(translate("salut tu vas bien?", "en"))
    hello you alright?'''

    agents = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30)"}


    before_trans = 'class="t0">'

    link = "http://translate.google.com/m?hl=%s&sl=%s&q=%s" % (to_langage, langage, urllib.quote(to_translate.encode('utf8')))

    request = urllib2.Request(link, headers=agents)

    page = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
    result = page[page.find(before_trans) + len(before_trans):]
    result = result.split("<")[0]

    return result
```

and i have this dictionary

user_all = {1: {0: [], 'Your Favorite 5 Songs': [u'lethe', u'suliman', u'converting vegetarians', u'invasion', u'betrayel'], 'Your Favorite 2 Writers': [u'ajdar', u'bulent ersoy'], 'Facebook Account Link': [''], 'Your Favorite 3 Movies': [u'hobbit', u'hobbit 2', u'hobbit 3'], 'Your Favorite 3 Singers': [u'infected mushroom', u'shiro sagisu', u'disturbed'], 'Timestamp': [''], 'Age': [''], 'Hobbies': [u'reading', u'horse riding', u'tiger hunting'], 'Your Favorite 3 Actors/Actress': [u'gerard butler', u'tom hanks', u'jonny deep'], 'Choose Your Favorite 3 Music Genres': [u'Blues'], 'Your Favorite Sport Team': [''], 'Gender': [u'male'], 'Hometown': [u'istanbul'], 'Department': [u'EEE'], 'Twitter Account Link': [''], 'Your Sehir Student Address': [u'talhatemiz@std.segir.edu.tr'], 'Your Favorite 3 Sport Branches': ['', '', ''], 'Choose Your Favorite 2 Book Genres': [u'Fantasy, Short Story Collections\xa0'], 'Your Favorite 2 Directors': [u'guy riche', u'david o runnell']}, 2: {0: [], 'Your Favorite 5 Songs': [u'Belief', u'Slow dancing in a burning room', u'seni cok istiyorum', u'one more cup of coffee', u'simple man'], 'Your Favorite 2 Writers': [u'J. K. Rowling', u'Sabahattin Ali'], 'Facebook Account Link': [u'dgsdg'], 'Your Favorite 3 Movies': [u'Hobbit', u'The Lord Of the rings', u'araba'], 'Your Favorite 3 Singers': [u'John Mayer', u'Yavuz Cetin', u'Led Zeppelin'], 'Timestamp': [''], 'Age': [''], 'Hobbies': [u'Playing Guitar', u'Reading book', u'futbol oynamak'], 'Your Favorite 3 Actors/Actress': [u'Johnny Depp', u'Natalie Portman', u'Mila Kunis'], 'Choose Your Favorite 3 Music Genres': [u'Blues, Indie, Rock'], 'Your Favorite Sport Team': [u'dsgg'], 'Gender': [u'Male'], 'Hometown': [u'Artvin'], 'Department': [u'EEE'], 'Twitter Account Link': [u'sdgsg'], 'Your Sehir Student Address': [u'Burak Altun'], 'Your Favorite 3 Sport Branches': [u'asd', u'asd', u'as\u015ffkndl'], 'Choose Your Favorite 2 Book Genres': [u'Action and Adventure, Science Fiction'], 'Your Favorite 2 Directors': [u'Steven Spielberg', u'Quentin Tarantino']}}

i code this to reach every word

```
 for i in user_all.values():
     for j in i.values():
          for m in j:
              self.translate(m, to_langage="en", langage="auto")
```

I am getting this error

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/baltun/Documents/workspace/SimSurve/src/Reader/trying_translate.py", line 99, in 
    print read.start_reading()

File "/Users/baltun/Documents/workspace/SimSurve/src/Reader/trying_translate.py", line 92, in start_reading
    self.translate(m, to_langage="en", langage="auto")

File "/Users/baltun/Documents/workspace/SimSurve/src/Reader/trying_translate.py", line 38, in translate
    page = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 397, in open
    response = meth(req, response)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 510, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 435, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 518, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Can you help me?

Comment: I suppose you have to encode your `link` string

Comment: I understood why it is happening. It can translate just one word, if it the string is more than one word it cannot translate. How i can solve this?

Comment: Can you add values of `to_langage`, `langage` and `to_translate` to your code? My bellow answer works for me.

Comment: Ok, you right, this url [link](http://translate.google.com/m?hl=en&sl=auto&q=Yavuz%20Cetin) return a `400 Bad Request`.

Answer (score 1):

```
# coding: utf8
import urllib
import urllib2

agents = {
    'User-Agent': "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30)"}

to_langage, langage, to_translate = 'en', 'fa',  u'سلام بر جهان'

before_trans = 'class="t0">'

link = "http://translate.google.com/m?hl=%s&sl=%s&q=%s" % (to_langage, langage, urllib.quote(to_translate.encode('utf8')))

request = urllib2.Request(link, headers=agents)

page = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
result = page[page.find(before_trans) + len(before_trans):]
result = result.split("<")[0]

print(result)

Hello World
```

OK,  this example works, but i found why you got 400 error.

In your `user_all` defined dictionary, there is a string `u'Yavuz Cetin'`, that contains `Yavu`.

In Turkish, the word `Yavu` means `slow` and so google translation for this word return HTTP 400 ERROR !!

To solve it, you may want to change this word in `user_all` defined dictionary or contact to google !!

Looks at [translate.google.com/m?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&ie=UTF-8&prev=_m&q=yavu](http://translate.google.com/m?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&ie=UTF-8&prev=_m&q=yavu) , and [google.com/search?q=google%20translate%20yavu%20400](https://www.google.com/search?q=google%20translate%20yavu%20400)

Comment: Now i got this problem @OmidRaha                          AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'encode'